# How to join a table and get results based on date difference limited to 1 per match?

Tags: mysql, date, join, limit

I've been searching around and working on this one all day but just cannot figure it out.

I have a table `trades` and this query involves 3 columns on the table: `provider_id`, `trade_id`, `date_close`.

For each final trade of the day (of a specified provider), I want to get the previous trade which closed 2 days or more prior...and was the final closing trade on that day. For example, from this:

```
+-------------+----------+---------------------+
| provider_id | trade_id | date_close          |
+-------------+----------+---------------------+
|      126    |        1 | 2012-10-22 14:26:57 |
|      126    |        2 | 2012-10-22 14:31:59 |
|      126    |        3 | 2012-10-23 12:39:41 |
|      126    |        4 | 2012-10-24 07:29:57 |
|      126    |        5 | 2012-10-24 08:36:19 |
|      126    |        6 | 2012-10-24 08:47:23 |
|      126    |        7 | 2012-10-25 08:30:11 |
|      126    |        8 | 2012-10-25 08:34:21 |
|      126    |        9 | 2012-10-26 08:43:12 |
|      126    |       10 | 2012-10-26 14:29:35 |
+-------------+----------+---------------------+
```

Desired output would be this:

```
+-----------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| atrade_id | adate_close         | btrade_id | bdate_close         |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
|         6 | 2012-10-24 08:47:23 |         2 | 2012-10-22 14:31:59 |
|         8 | 2012-10-25 08:34:21 |         3 | 2012-10-23 12:39:41 |
|        10 | 2012-10-26 14:29:35 |         6 | 2012-10-24 08:47:23 |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Here is the query I've created so far:

```
SELECT a.trade_id atrade_id, MAX(a.date_close) adate_close, b.trade_id btrade_id, MAX(b.date_close) bdate_close
FROM trades a
INNER JOIN trades b ON a.provider_id = b.provider_id
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, DATE_FORMAT(b.date_close, "%Y-%m-%d"), DATE_FORMAT(a.date_close, "%Y-%m-%d")) >= 2
AND a.provider_id = 126
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.date_close, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I wanted to set a `LIMIT 1 DESC` on the `date_close` columns so as to get only the final closing trade on those days. But could not figure out how to do this, so I'm using `MAX()`. I'm guessing there must be a better way. Also, while the query above gets me close, it returns btrade_id as 1 on all results, and the atrade_id values are off too:

```
+-----------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| atrade_id | adate_close         | btrade_id | bdate_close         |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
|         4 | 2012-10-24 08:47:23 |         1 | 2012-10-22 14:31:59 |
|         7 | 2012-10-25 08:34:21 |         1 | 2012-10-23 12:39:41 |
|         9 | 2012-10-26 14:29:35 |         1 | 2012-10-24 08:47:23 |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong, or a better way I could go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following query that should deliver the desired output. It uses two nested subqueries to select the appropriate closing trade:

```
SELECT  PREV_CLOSE.atrade_id atrade_id,
        PREV_CLOSE.adate_close atrade_close,
        B2.trade_id btrade_id,
        B2.date_close bdate_close
FROM (
    SELECT  FINAL_CLOSE.provider_id,
            A.trade_id atrade_id, 
            A.date_close adate_close,
            MAX(B.date_close) prev_date_close
    FROM (
        SELECT  provider_id, MAX(date_close) final_date_close
        FROM    trades
        GROUP BY provider_id, DATE(date_close)
    ) FINAL_CLOSE
    JOIN        trades A ON A.provider_id = FINAL_CLOSE.provider_id AND A.date_close = FINAL_CLOSE.final_date_close
    LEFT JOIN   trades B ON B.provider_id = FINAL_CLOSE.provider_id AND B.date_close < DATE(FINAL_CLOSE.final_date_close) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    GROUP BY FINAL_CLOSE.provider_id, A.trade_id
) PREV_CLOSE
JOIN    trades B2 ON B2.provider_id = PREV_CLOSE.provider_id AND B2.date_close = PREV_CLOSE.prev_date_close
```

Since I assume that your trade table might be huge, you definitely want to create an index over `provider_id` and `date_close` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `trades` ADD INDEX ( `provider_id` , `date_close` );
```

Otherwise, your query will be very unlikely to terminate as soon as your trades table grows to several ten or even hundred thousands of records.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am going to need to study what you are doing with that query, as it is on a level much higher than my current ability with MySQL so far. I have tested it, and can confirm that it works like a charm.

To get my desired output I've added this to the end of the query:

`WHERE B2.provider_id = 126
ORDER BY atrade_id`

Comment: Also, you are correct that this table will be huge. I have a FOREIGN KEY on provider_id, and an INDEX on date_close at the moment. I hope that will help to speed things up. I currently have almost 3500 rows in the table, but it will get to hundreds of thousands. This query takes about 1.4 seconds so far. Sorry that I can't vote up your reply as I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help :) to optimize, I'd try different indexes, e.g. add the (provider_id, date_close) index and look how long the query takes, and of course use EXPLAIN SELECT PREV_CLOSE.atrade_id ... to see which indexes are chosen by MySQL.